# GCD and LCM in prolog

Tags: prolog, greatest-common-divisor, successor-arithmetics

Some code could help

```
%addition
sum(X,nil,X).
sum(X,s(Y),s(Z)) :- sum(X,Y,Z).

%Product
mult(X,nil,nil).
mult(X,s(Y),W) :- mult(X,Y,Z),sum(X,Z,W).
```

I am trying to solve a simple problem in prolog "GCD and LCM **peano number** "

I don't know how to start  ?

How to compare piano's number in prolog
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Start by first thinking, independent of Prolog, how you would define GCD and LCM algorithmically in terms of your fundamental operations (`sum` and `mult`). By the way, `sum/3` should also enable you to subtract since it's an inverse operation and `sum` should be relational.

Comment: Regarding the code you provided, did you write it? Did  you test it to see if those predicates work as expected?

Comment: Yes I test the code sum and mult it work

Comment: How to compare Peano numbers

Comment: How would you define when two Peano numbers are equal? Or one less than another? Start with that, then translate to Prolog.

Comment: oh right it should be like this ; 'prod(0,M,0).prod(s(N),M,P):-prod(N,M,K),sum(K,M,P).' Now this code right ,Thank u

Comment: sum(0,M,M).sum(s(N),M,s(K)):- sum(N,M,K).

Comment: please note the `nil` vs `0` confusion. Rather use `0`!

Comment: @Marcin, your question is not specific to SWI, therefore the tag [tag:swi-prolog] is not appropriate.

Comment: Here's are some hints regarding how to compare piano numbers. `s(X)` and `s(Y)` are equal if `X` and `Y` are equal. `s(_)` is greater than 0. `p(_)` is less than 0. Write out what you think your rules are in that fashion. Then worry about how to write that in Prolog. A Prolog predicate basically says "such and such is true *if* (`:-`) something else is true".